# Intervals as countable unions and intersections.

Tags: real-analysis

We consider the following equalities in the exetended real line. Let $a,b$ be a real numbers: $$[-\infty,b)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \big[-\infty, b-\frac{1}{n}\big]\tag1$$

$$[a,\infty]=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \left(a-\frac{1}{n},\infty\right]\tag2$$

$$(a,+\infty]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[a+\frac{1}{n}, \infty\right]\tag3$$

$$[-\infty, b]=\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty[-\infty, b+\frac{1}{n}]\tag4$$

I think they are correct, I proved them. I'm just not so sure. Could you tell me if they are correct?

Comment: From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

Comment: @MartinR Excuse me. I'm not asking for formal proof, I'm asking if these equalities make sense.

Comment: What does it mean to include $-\infty$?

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I corrected

Comment: It is uncommon to see a square bracket on a side that has an infinity symbol as $\infty$ is not a real number.  More commonly, we write $[a,\infty)$ to represent the set $\{x\in\Bbb R~:~x\geq a\}$.  Writing $[a,\infty]$ makes it *seem* like you intend to be working with extended reals (*uncommon choice*) and working with "intervals" $[a,\infty]=\{x\in\Bbb R~:~x\geq a\}\cup \{\infty\}$.  This feels non-standard, and I hesitate to actually call these intervals.

Comment: As already mentionned in previous comments, usually people use the open interval sign for infinity since it is not a number and thus never contained in the interval. Apart from that, the equalities are true.

Comment: @VincentBatens Thanks, maybe I should have said in the post that I'm working on the extended real line.

Comment: @NatMath Ah it should still be true though.